# How to stop the time of a scroll-snap transition

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, scroll-snap

I'm actually trying to make a similar scroll effect than this website : https://kuon.space/

I've made something using scroll-snap but I want, like the site, to disable free scroll, if someone scroll the scroll-snap animation start immediately and show the div above or below, with that the user will not be able to scroll freely on the site and will have to pass all the div one by one if he want to go to the top / bottom of the site (like the site I put above)
So I'm asking help because I'm litteraly stuck, I don't now where to start

Did this include to make js or css only can work ? Thanks by advance!